# Will a newer Shimano series cassette be easily interchangeable?

Tags: shimano, cassette

I'm trying to create two wheelsets that I can quickly swap out on the same bike for different conditions.  My existing set has a [Shimano 105 5800 series 11 speed cassette](https://bike.shimano.com/en-EU/product/component/105-5800/CS-5800.html).  They discontinued that so you pretty much can only find the newer [Shimano 105 7000 series 11 speed cassette](https://bike.shimano.com/en-EU/product/component/shimano105-r7000/CS-R7000.html).

While reading [a review](https://road.cc/content/review/248560-shimano-105-r7000-groupset) of the newer series, it was mentioned that:

> It's designed to also fit a mountain bike wheel, so you need the optional spacer if you're fitting it to an 11-speed road wheelset.

My question is, will the spacer requirement on the new cassette with my road bike force me to mess with my rear derailleur indexing/etc. when I swap the wheelset/cassette?

[image: Shimano 7000 Cassette]

Comment: Keep in mind that Shimano and SRAM cassettes are interchangeable where you might find a cassette of the desired range.

Comment: I'm guessing, but different model hubs may place the cassette in a slightly different position anyway, requiring a little rear derailleur tweaking when swapping wheels.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The spacer is required for 11-34 cassette only, same story as CS-R8000 11-34. The 34t cog hangs over freehub body, which allows to use the good old 8-10 speed HG freehub body. For a note, Shimano MTB 11 speed cassettes do not require 11-speed specific freehub body either.

[image]

> My question is, will the spacer requirement on the new cassette with
>   my road bike force me to mess with my rear derailleur indexing/etc.
>   when I swap the wheelset/cassette?

To be honest, I did not run this cassette, but it would make no sense to change offset just because it uses a carrier spider instead of cogs riveted together. At worst, you'd have to put a thin spacer under the cassette when swapping it between 11-34 and smaller range options like 11-28.